# what are the advantages of done() method in $.ajax instead of success()

Tags: jquery, ajax

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("_sampleMethod","Sample")',
  type: 'GET',
  cache: false,
}).done(function (result) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Both are proprietary and likely to be removed in the future so neither should be used now.  Use the ES6 promise standard `.then()` instead which jQuery also supports.

Comment: does then() cover purpose of both of them.

Comment: Yes, `.then()` is all you need and it is the ES6 promise standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`done()` method is helpful when there is a series of multiple Ajax calls and one waits on other to complete the callbacks. So that only after Ajax call A gets completed you execute your post Ajax code in `done()` . While `success()` is mainly a part of a single Ajax call that helps you process the response according to your needs .

Answer (score 1):

`success` only fires if the AJAX call is successful, i.e. ultimately returns a HTTP 200 status. `error` fires if it fails and `complete` when the request finishes, regardless of success.

In jQuery 1.8 on the `jqXHR` object (returned by `$.ajax`) `success` is being replaced with `done`, `error` with `fail` and `complete` with always.

However you should still be able to initialise the AJAX request with the current syntax. So these do similar things:

```
// set success action before making the request
$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  success: function(){
    alert('AJAX successful');
  }
});

// set success action just after starting the request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "..." )
  .done(function() { alert("success"); });
```

I think this change is for compatibility with jQuery 1.5's new deferred object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not well formatted, but I will give it a shot anyway.

done() triggers your function regardless if the ajax request was successful or not.

success() triggers your function only if your ajax request was successful.

Answer (score 0):

success has been the traditional name of the success callback in jQuery, defined as an option in the ajax call. However, since the implementation of $.Deferreds and more sophisticated callbacks, done is the preferred way to implement success callbacks, as it can be called on any deferred example of success

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/',
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

done example

```
$.ajax({url: '/'}).done(function(data) {});
```

The nice thing about done is that the return value of $.ajax is now a deferred promise that can be bound to anywhere else in your application. So let's say you want to make this ajax call from a few different places. Rather than passing in your success function as an option to the function that makes this ajax call, you can just have the function return $.ajax itself and bind your callbacks with done, fail, then, or whatever. Note that always is a callback that will run whether the request succeeds or fails. done will only be triggered on success.